# Python/Pandas : Issues with apply function on a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I'm scraping data from the website clinicaltrial.gov with pytrial and the retrieved data is a table of list.

I need to convert it to a string format when there's only one item on the list so I made a simple function to convert the List to a string.

```
def convertListString(List):
    newList=List
    if len(List)==1:
        newList = List[0]
    return newList
```

It's working well when I'm using the apply function on a single column.

```
df['NCTId'].apply(convertListString)
```

But when I'm using it on the dataFrame, it returns the same dataframe without any errors and without formatting.

```
df.apply(convertListString)
```

Edit: It works when I apply a function that just multiply the object by 2

Thanks for your help

Comment: when you run with more columns then you get `row` , not single `cell` - and you would have to use `for`-loop to check every value in row.

Answer (score 1):

`DataFrame.apply(func)` passes column to `func` by default, you may want `DataFrame.applymap`

```py
df.applymap(convertListString)
```